# How i can to pass parameter to model method in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hi everyone i have a question about django template and models method include function parameter.

example code in models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     price = models.IntegerField()
     owner = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def get_something(self,requestuser): # <-- pass request.user here
         // calculate something here 
         return "output"
```

in views.py

```
def assets(request):
     return render(request, 'index.html', {'items':Item.objects.filter(owner=request.user)})
```

in template

```
{% for item in items %}
   <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
   <h2>{{item.price}}</h2>
   <h2>{{item.get_something(request.user) }}</h2> <!-- How to inject request.user to get_something Here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You filter the items by `owner=request.user`, can you not just use `self.owner` in the method? You can't pass arguments to functions in Django templates without some custom tag/filter

Comment: Lain Shelvington is right... You can't unless you use a custom filter tag within your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom tag for that case. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-custom-template-tags-in-django/)
. I also had to build it for my project as I had to send arguments from template to my model's method.
I created a folder in my app called templatetags and inside that folder was my `__init__.py` and `myTags.py`:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def call_method(obj, method_name, *args):
    method = getattr(obj, method_name)
    return method(*args)
```

then in template first I import my tags then I use my custom tag:

```
{% load myTags %}


{% call_method model 'method' argument1 argument2 argument3... %}
```

Comment: excuse me . how i can to add IF such as
{% if call_method model 'method' argument1 argument2 argument3... %}

Comment: You can store the method's return value in variable like:
{% call_method model 'method' argument1 argument2 argument3... as var %} 
and then you can use your variable like:
{% if var %}